# What is --from used in copy command in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am seeing a dockerfile whose code is given below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FirstDockerApp/FirstDockerApp.csproj", "FirstDockerApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FirstDockerApp/FirstDockerApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FirstDockerApp"
RUN dotnet build "FirstDockerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FirstDockerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FirstDockerApp.dll"]
```

On the 2nd last line there is `COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`. I don't understand why --from is used and what purpose it solves. Can you please help me to understand it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is a multi-stage build. This is used to keep the running docker container small while still be able to build/compile things needing a lot of dependencies.

For example a go application could be built by using:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

So in the first part we need a complete go environment to compile our software. Notice the name for the first part and the alias `builder`

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 AS builder
```

In the second part beginning from the second FROM we only need the compiled app and no other go dependencies anymore. So we can change the base image to using a much smaller alpine Linux.
But the compiled files are still in our builder image and not part of the image we want to start.
So we need to copy files from the builder image via

```
COPY --from=builder
```

You can have as many stages as you want. The last one is the one defining the image which will be the template for the docker container.

You can read more about it in the official documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: The docs also mention variants: If you don't name the build stages, you can use the index to reference the build stage you want: `COPY --from=0` although this might be more fragile. (And you can also reference image names: `COPY --from=nginx:latest /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /nginx.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explaination of multi-stage builds.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, if you didn't have the `COPY --from=builder` in the second section, then Docker would just build the last image (and skip the first one)? And, if you use a `COPY --from=...`, then Docker will automatically see that dependency and build it first?

Comment: @DerekMorrison it depends on the docker builder used. Normally Dockerfiles are processed top to bottom, regardless if needed or referenced at all. However with BuildKit it would skip the parts not needed. This is explained in the multistage documentation. You can easly check this by writing some Dockerfiles and checking the output of the build command, which is verbose enough to see what is build/cached/skipped

Answer (score 6):

Comment from https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

> "You can use the COPY --from instruction to copy from a separate
> image, either using the local image name, a tag available locally or
> on a Docker registry, or a tag ID. The Docker client pulls the image
> if necessary and copies the artifact from there."

Basically, COPY --from is used for the multistage build.

Answer (score 3):

you'll find this commonly in a multi-stage docker build.

As you can see there's four build stage there. The `base`, `build`, `publish`, and `final` build. In the `final` build, on the third instruction, you can see that you're copying a file from the previous build, the `publish` build.

Your third build, the `publish` build, is creating something in the `/app/publish` directory. So, in order to access that directory and copy the content inside it, your `final` build (third instruction) is copying from that directory using `--from=publish` so you can access the directory from the previous build.